# Why does this very small C program use up so much memory?

Tags: c, memory

```
int i = 0;

int main(){
  while (true){
    i = 1;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

The above program, (compiled with gnu g++, no extra compiler flags) which just loops forever, seems to use up more memory than it should (output of top shown below):

```
  PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND                                                                                
 9392 root      20   0    4376    788    728 R 100.0  0.0   2:32.65 a.out
```

I get why the CPU usage is 100%, since it is constantly spinning in the while loop. Why is VIRT sitting at 4MB? Why is SHR sitting at 728KB? I am using no libraries. Finally, and most importantly, why the usage of 788KB to store just one variable? And where/how is the remaining (4376-788)KB being stored/used?

Comment: Not really a C question but more of a platform / operating system thing, but I'm guessing there is a 4 MB stack.

Comment: You're probably getting the whole (shared) C library.

Comment: Good points, I'd like to know exactly how one might verify with certainty whether these suspicions are correct.

Comment: "I am using no libraries." This is an illusion. Your program still uses the *C runtime* which contains standard startup code and standard termination code and Bob knows what else. If you really need to use *no* libraries you probanly want to explore -nostartfiles and -nostdlib flags at least. Note, this requires modification to your source code.

Comment: `Why is VIRT sitting at 4MB?` Virtual memory is spent by pages. Say 2mb per page, one code, and one data.

Comment: @Matt You got it totally wrong. 4kB pages are the default, using 2MB huge pages requires extra work and you missed stack in your breakdown. Note that "2mb" reads "2 milli-bits", use the right prefixes https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_prefix and units.

Answer (score 4):

> Why is VIRT sitting at 4MB? Why is SHR sitting at 728kB? I am using no libraries.

That is not accurate.

Let's compile:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    char buf[100];
    snprintf(buf, sizeof buf, "pmap -x %u", (unsigned)getpid());
    system(buf);
}
```

With command `gcc -o test -W{all,extra,error} -xc test.cc`.

And run it:

```
$ ./test
7360:   ./test
Address           Kbytes     RSS   Dirty Mode   Mapping
0000000000400000       4       4       4 r-x--  test
0000000000600000       4       4       4 rw---  test
00007f1f4d96a000    1580     788       0 r-x--  libc-2.12.so
00007f1f4daf5000    2044       0       0 -----  libc-2.12.so
00007f1f4dcf4000      16      16      16 r----  libc-2.12.so
00007f1f4dcf8000       8       8       8 rw---  libc-2.12.so
00007f1f4dcfa000      16       8       8 rw---    [ anon ]
00007f1f4dcfe000     128     128       0 r-x--  ld-2.12.so
00007f1f4df0c000      12      12      12 rw---    [ anon ]
00007f1f4df1d000       4       4       4 rw---    [ anon ]
00007f1f4df1e000       4       4       4 r----  ld-2.12.so
00007f1f4df1f000       4       4       4 rw---  ld-2.12.so
00007f1f4df20000       4       4       4 rw---    [ anon ]
00007ffd4a872000     132      12      12 rw---    [ stack ]
00007ffd4a961000      12       0       0 r----    [ anon ]
00007ffd4a964000       8       4       0 r-x--    [ anon ]
ffffffffff600000       4       0       0 r-x--    [ anon ]
----------------  ------  ------  ------
total kB            3984    1000      80
```

(If you see duplicate lines in `pmap -x` output, this was a [bug](https://gitlab.com/procps-ng/procps/commit/b899c55dca00eee8dd9c29bbc4b32f3598ad51f6) in older versions).

It loads:

- `test` - the executable.
- `libc.so` - C standard library.
- `ld.so` - the dynamic linker.

The shared libraries are loaded into the virtual address space of the process at addresses below the address space reserved for thread stacks, each next library loads at a lower address. `ld.so` normally loads first.

The 1000kB of RSS are occupied by:

- 920kB is executable code of your executable (4kB) and the shared libraries (pages with `r-x--` mode)
- 12kB is stack (marked as `[ stack ]`).
- Pages marked as `[ anon ]` with `rw---` mode are heap and 0-initialized data with static storage duration from `.bss` sections of the executable and shared libraries.
- The rest is read-only and non-0-initialized data with static storage duration from `.data` and `.rodata` (`r----` mode) sections of the executable and shared libraries.

Answer (score 3):

Most of the memory overhead that surprises you comes from the C library and the dynamic linker, which will be fully loaded into memory even though you aren't using them ... much.  (You *are* using them for a glob of code that runs before `main`, which many people don't realize exists, but it's there.  It's responsible for things like setting up stdio, running C++ global constructors, and arranging for it to be possible to return from `main` without crashing.)

For comparison, this is just about the smallest busy-wait program you can have on Linux/x86 without [hand-hacking the ELF file format](https://www.muppetlabs.com/~breadbox/software/tiny/teensy.html):

```
$ cat tiny.s
    .text
    .globl _start
    .type _start,@function
_start:
    pause
    jmp _start
    .size _start, .-_start
    .section .note.GNU-stack,"",@progbits
```

I've written it in assembly language so I can chop out all of the overhead associated with the C library.  In order to exclude the code that runs before `main`, I have to name my program's "main function" `_start` instead.  Compile thus:

```
$ gcc -nostdlib -nostartfiles -static -Wl,--build-id=none -o tiny tiny.s
```

`-nostdlib` to turn off most of the C library, `-nostartfiles` to turn off the code that runs before `main`, `-static` so it won't even pull in the dynamic linker, and `-Wl,--build-id=none` to suppress an annotation that makes the executable significantly bigger on disk. Here's what that gets us:

```
$ objdump -dr tiny

tiny:     file format elf64-x86-64


Disassembly of section .text:

0000000000401000 <_start>:
  401000:   f3 90                   pause  
  401002:   eb fc                   jmp    401000 <_start>

$ size tiny
   text    data     bss     dec     hex filename
      4       0       0       4       4 a.out
$ ls -l tiny
-rwxr-xr-x 1 zack zack 4632 Nov 27 10:53 tiny
```

Four bytes of actual machine instructions.  They get enlarged to slightly more than 4k of complete executable file with more padding and annotations.  You can use the `objdump` and `readelf` commands to poke through the file and see what-all is in there.

Here's how it shows up in `top`:

```
  PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU  %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND  
12154 zack      20   0     156      4      0 R 100.0   0.0   0:16.51 a.out
```

This still allocates 156kB¹ of address space and 4kB of actual RAM.  To find out in more detail what this space is going to, we can look at `/proc/<pid>/maps` for the process: (note, the output on your system may differ a little)

```
$ cat /proc/12514/maps
000000400000-000000401000 r--p 00000000 fd:01 26477890    /home/zack/tiny
000000401000-000000402000 r-xp 00001000 fd:01 26477890    /home/zack/tiny
7fff5c9b3000-7fff5c9d4000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0           [stack]
7fff5c9fb000-7fff5c9fe000 r--p 00000000 00:00 0           [vvar]
7fff5c9fe000-7fff5c9ff000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0           [vdso]
```

There are five virtual memory allocations, with the first two numbers on each line being their starting and ending addresses, respectively.  The first 0x1000 bytes (4kB) of the executable file have been mapped read-only, and the second 4kB of the executable file have been mapped read-execute.  (Yes, this means the file is shorter than its memory map.  The kernel will fill in the gap with zeroes.)  Then we have 
0x7fff5c9d4000 − 0x7fff5c9b3000 = 132kB allocated to the stack, 12kB allocated to "vvar", and 4kB allocated to "vdso".  8 + 132 + 12 + 4 = 156kB.

An interesting fact visible here: `top`'s RES counts only pages that have been committed to the current process.  In this case, that's one page of the *stack* allocation.  The 8kB of mappings from the executable file are *not* counted, because they are read-only, shareable, and discardable -- if you had many processes running this same program, they would all share the same copy of the program code in physical RAM, and if the kernel needs to kick those pages out of RAM to make room for something else, it doesn't have to write them to the swap file.  (The `top` manpage says something different about RES, but as far as I can tell, it's wrong.)

The "vvar" and "vdso" mappings are small globs of data and code, respectively, provided to all user space processes on Linux by the kernel.  They are for low-level tricks like making it possible to do a `gettimeofday` without actually switching the CPU into kernel mode.  This cuts out several thousand cycles of overhead, which matters for accurate timekeeping.  As far as I know, there's no way to turn these off.

---

You can reduce the size of the stack allocation with the `ulimit` command.  For instance, `ulimit -s 4` cuts it to the absolute minimum, 4kB.  If I run my program like this

```
$ (unset $(printenv | cut -d= -f1); ulimit -s 4; exec ./tiny)
```

then `top` reports

```
    PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU  %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND
  14293 zack      20   0      28      4      0 R 100.0   0.0   0:06.02 tiny
```

and the `stack` line in `/proc/14293/maps` reads

```
7ffdf80e5000-7ffdf80e6000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0              [stack]
```

But without that initial `unset` command (which clears all the environment variables), the program crashes on startup:

```
$ (ulimit -s 4; exec ./tiny)
Segmentation fault
```

This is because the kernel writes a bunch of data into the stack allocation -- the command-line argument vector, all the environment variables, and the [ELF auxiliary vector](https://lwn.net/Articles/519085/) -- before it starts the program running.  If I don't clear the environment variables, that data takes up more than 4kB of space and the program crashes.  I bet you didn't know it was possible to trigger a segfault *inside the `execve` system call*.

---

¹ Proper, binary kilobytes, that is: 1kB ≝ 1024 bytes.  Do not listen to anyone who tells you different, not even the International Bureau of Weights and Measures.